Real coefficients polynomial $P_n(\alpha)=0,|\alpha|=1\implies \alpha^{n+1}=1$


Let $0<a_n\leq a_{n-1}\leq\cdots\leq a_1\leq a_0$ and
$$P_n(z)=a_nz^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1z+a_0.$$
If there exists $\alpha\in\mathbb C$ with $|\alpha|=1$ such that $P_n(\alpha)=0$,
then $\alpha^{n+1}=1$.


My idea: obviously $\alpha\neq1$ and  when $n$ is $even$ we have $P_n(-1)>0$,
but when $n$ is $odd$, it may have $P_n(-1)=0$.
When $n=1$, $P_1(z)=a_1z+a_0$, $P_1(\alpha)=P_1(1/\alpha)=0\implies \alpha=-1,a_1=a_0$, so $\alpha^2=1$;
When $n=2$, $P_2(z)=a_2z^2+a_1z+a_0$,
$$P_2(\alpha)=P_2(1/\alpha)=0\implies a_2\alpha^2+a_1\alpha+a_0=0\ (1),\ a_2+a_1\alpha+a_0\alpha^2=0\ (2).$$
$(1)-(2)$ implies $(a_2-a_0)(\alpha^2-1)=0$, which implies $a_2=a_1=a_0$.
So $\alpha$ is a zero of $z^2+z+1$, hence $\alpha^3=1$.
In general, I wanto to prove $a_n=a_{n-1}=\cdots=a_1=a_0$, which implies
$\alpha$ is a zero of $z^n+\cdots+z+1$, hence $\alpha^{n+1}=1$.
But I have no further method to do this!
Any hints or ideas will welcome, thanks a lot.

Why is $P(\frac{1}{\alpha})$ the same as $P(\alpha)$? You're correct maybe, but I don't understand. Thanks for the explanation in advance

@
Gwen
$\bar{\alpha}=1/\alpha$ and real coefficients .

Note that $(1-z)P(z)=a_0+(a_1-a_0)z+\cdots+(a_n-a_{n-1})z^n-a_nz^{n+1}$, so $$0=|(1-\alpha)P(\alpha)| \ge a_0-|(a_1-a_0)\alpha+\cdots+(a_n-a_{n-1})\alpha^n-a_n\alpha^{n+1}|.$$
But $|(a_1-a_0)\alpha+\cdots+(a_n-a_{n-1})\alpha^n-a_n\alpha^{n+1}| \le (a_0-a_1)+\cdots+(a_{n-1}-a_n)+a_n=a_0$ by the triangle inequality and the hypothesis on the monotonicity and positivity of the $a_k$, so from the above we get $0 \ge a_0-a_0=0$ hence we must have equality in every triangle inequality we use.
If $a_{n-1}-a_n >0$ it follows (by applying the triangle inequality first with those two terms separate) that $|(a_{n-1}-a_n)\alpha^n+\alpha^{n+1}a_n|=|(a_{n-1}-a_n)+\alpha a_n|=|(a_{n-1}-a_n)|+|\alpha a_n|$ which means (by squaring) that $\alpha=1$ and that is impossible so $a_{n-1}=a_n$ and then it's clear how we continue to deduce that all $a_k$ must be equal and then we are done!

Thank  you for your nice answer!

happy to be of help
